# Best practices for creating CRUD services in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, crud

What is the best practice for designing CRUD services / factories within an AngularJS application that process **single** and **multiple** entities?

For example I have a `customer` object in a factory called `customerFactory` that contains a structure similar to this:

```
var customer = {
    newCustomer: false,
    selfUri: null,
    editUri: null,
    deleteUri: null,
    customerName: null,
    customerAddress: null
};
```

And that I also have the following example functions exposed on that factory that call REST services:

```
var create = function() {
    $http.post('api/customers/1', { customer: customer } );
}

var read = function() {
    $http.get('api/customers', { params { uri : customer.selfUri } );
}

var update  = function() {
    $http.put('api/customers/1', { customer: customer } );
}

var delete = function() {
    $http.delete('api/customers/1', { uri: customer.deleteUri } );
}

// This is an oddity and probably shouldn't be in this factory??
var readAll = function() {
    $http.get('api/customers', {} );
}
```

All of these methods basically work on the `customer` object within the factory.

Should the `readAll()` method be put into a different service / factory that handles retrieving ALL customers rather than put into the above factory as it deals with **single** entities?  Should REST calls that retrieve multiple entities be placed into it's own factory?

**Example: `customerFactory`**

```
// Deal with single customer entities
app.factory('customerFactory', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        var customerFactory = {};

        var customer = {
            newCustomer: false,
            selfUri: null,
            editUri: null,
            deleteUri: null,
            customerName: null,
            customerAddress: null
        };

        var create = function() {
            $http.post('api/customers/1', { customer: customer } );
        }

        var read = function() {
            $http.get('api/customers', { params { uri : customer.selfUri } );
        }

        var update  = function() {
            $http.put('api/customers/1', { customer: customer } );
        }

        var delete = function() {
            $http.delete('api/customers/1', { uri: customer.deleteUri } );
        }

        customerFactory.create = create;
        customerFactory.read= read;
        customerFactory.update= update;
        customerFactory.create = delete;

       return customerFactory;

    }]);
```

**Example: `customersFactory`**

```
// Deal with multiple customer entities
app.factory('customersFactory', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        var customersFactory = {};
        var customers = {};

        var readAll = function() {
        $http.get('api/customers', {} ).then(function(response) {
            customers.push(response.data);
        });

        customersFactory.readAll = readAll;

        return customersFactory;

    }]);
```

Comment: Wow.... you are converting rails way into angularJS. very interesting. I think you should go with this,  if you are comfortable with it. Perhaps, the naming customerFactory and customersFactory are hard to distinguished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me preface by saying I am pretty new to angular. With that said, you can create a CustomerClass that is used in the CustomerList and Customer services. The customerlist service will return an array, whereas the customer service will return a single customer. Even though I add them to the app with .factory(), they are used as services.

Notice that CustomerClass only returns the function (class) without a new keyword. This is so that you can instantiate a new CustomerClass on your own in the other services. The self.init function is the constructor and it will automatically extend the values of an object that you pass in. Self.init is called automatically right under the declaration.

I use Self.ready in my factories so that if I am using ng-repeat, it won't show unless the factory has a status of ready=true. Because you are pulling data in an ajaxy way, you don't want to update the views with anything until the data is received and ready.

```
myApp.factory("CustomerClass", function ($http) {
    function CustomerClass(extendableObject) {

        var self = this;
        self.init = function () {
            //will extend newCustomer, selfUri, editUri etc... fields
            angular.extend(self, extendableObject);
        };
        self.init();
    }

    return CustomerClass;
});

myApp.factory("CustomerListService", function ($http, CustomerClass) {
    function CustomerList() {
        var self = this;
        self.ready = false;
        //return array of customer objects
        self.readAll = function () {
            var customers = [];
            $http.get('api/customers/list')
                .success(function (payload) {
                    angular.forEach(payload.customers, function (customer) {
                        customers.push(new CustomerClass(customer));
                    });
                    self.ready = true;
                    return customers;
                });
        };
    }

    return new CustomerList;
});

myApp.factory("CustomerService", function ($http, CustomerClass) {

    function Customer() {
        var self = this;
        self.ready = false;
        //return one customer object
        self.read = function (id) {
            $http.get('api/customers/single', {params: {id: id}})
                .success(function (payload) {
                    return new CustomerClass(payload);
                    self.ready = true;
                });
        };
    }

    return new Customer;
});
```

Comment: This looks like a good, clean solution.  How would I use `self.ready` with `ng-repeat`?  Can you clarify this with an example as I'm relatively new to angular as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, I though I was going to make a "quick" plunker of this little project, and it ended taking a lot longer since I guess I don't know angular as well as I thought. I ended up learning way more so it was as much for me as you. I tried to comment fairly well, but some prereqs are knowing about defer ($q) and obviously object oriented javascript. Good luck! and just ask if there's problems. http://plnkr.co/edit/0dlwDW?p=info

Comment: Also, my answer above was close, but not exactly correct. There's some typos and conceptual errors. The plunker is much better

Comment: I have taken a look at your plunker and it looks really good and helpful.  Thanks for taking the time out to do this for me as it'll help me greatly. I'll let you know if I need any further help :)

Comment: How do I use the `customerList` service in a controller when I need to select the first customer in the list, e.g. `$scope.selected = { item: customerList.customers[0] };` ?  I am getting `ready=false` which indicates the service hasn't finished populating `customerList`.  Also how I pass in `id` for the `customerSingle.getOneCustomer` method?  I'm assuming I just need to add a parameter to `init()` and remove the `self.init()` method call?

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer you to use `$resource` that will suits better in your case.

Only you need to write a single method inside a service that can remove your all redundant code of your service like it'll act as `GET, PUT, DELETE & UPDATE`

**Factory CODE**

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp',['ngResource']);
app.factory('Customer', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/customers/:id'); // Note the full endpoint address
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('CustomerController', function($scope, Customer) {
    var customer = Customer.get({ id: $scope.id }, function() {
        console.log(customer);
    }); // get() returns a single entry

    var customers = Customer.query(function() {
        console.log(customers);
    }); //query() returns all the customers

    $scope.customer = new Customer(); //You can instantiate resource class

    $scope.customer.data = 'some data';

    Customer.save($scope.customer, function() {
        //data saved. do something here.
    }); //saves an customer. Assuming $scope.customer is the Entry object  
});
```

By using single service method you can do many thing. I'd prefer using `$resource` when dealing with **REST API**

For more detailed information do [**visit here**](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/)

**Update**

If you still want to stick with `$http` For making your code more reusable i'll avoid to create `customerFactory` which is having all methods related to customer, Rather than that I'd love to create `angular.constant`, by using that constant array we'll create a new service using that array.

**Constant**

```
app.constant('customerMethods', [
            {name: 'create', type: 'post', url: 'api/customers/1', dataParam:{ customer: customer }},
            {name: 'read', type: 'get', url: 'api/customers', dataParam:{ params: { uri : customer.selfUri }},
            {name: 'create', type: 'post', url: 'api/customers/1, dataParam:{ customer: customer }}, //you need to provide customer object
            {name: 'create', type: 'post', 'api/customers/1', dataParam: { customer: customer }},//you need to provide customer object
]);
```

**Factory**

```
app.factory('customersFactory', ['$http', 'customerMethods', 'customer',
    function($http, customerMethods, customer) {
        var customersFactory = {};
        var customers = {};
        var customerMethods = customerMethods;

        angular.forEach(customerMethods, function(val, index) {
            angular.extend(customersFactory, {
                val.name: function() {
                    return $http[val.type](val.url, val.dataParam);
                }
            });
        });

        return customersFactory;

    }
]);
```

Your re-factored code will look like above. Though it is not tested, but I'm sure the way would be like this only.

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't really answered my question of whether I should have separate services for dealing with single and multiple entities, although I will take on board your suggestion of using `$resource` to communicate with REST services as that seems to be much cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Communicating with Rest API should be always been implement using `$resource` which internally uses `$httpProvider` of angular

Comment: I am currently implementing @1Mike12's answer and will be looking at your answer later in the week once the code base is stable.

Comment: @Intrepid Cool..May be you considered my way is difficult to implement.

Comment: I will consider using $resource() after I have read the link about creating a CRUD app in minutes. I am not sure how to accept two answers as I am also using the solution given by @1mike12.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71106/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-intrepid).